# Return True if all characters in a string are in another string

Tags: python, string, boolean

Alright so for this problem I am meant to be writing a function that returns True if a given string contains only characters from another given string. So if I input "bird" as the first string and "irbd" as the second, it would return True, but if I used "birds" as the first string and "irdb" as the second it would return False. My code so far looks like this:

```
def only_uses_letters_from(string1,string2):
"""Takes two strings and returns true if the first string only contains characters also in the second string.

string,string -> string"""
if string1 in string2:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

When I try to run the script it only returns True if the strings are in the exact same order or if I input only one letter ("bird" or "b" and "bird" versus "bird" and "irdb").

Comment: `string1 in string2 == True` iff `string1` is a sub-string of `string2`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a perfect use case of [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). The following code will solve your problem:

```
def only_uses_letters_from(string1, string2):
   """Check if the first string only contains characters also in the second string."""
   return set(string1) <= set(string2)
```

Comment: Close.  Change `<` to `<=` -- otherwise `only_uses_letters_from("bird", "bird") => False`

Answer (score 5):

sets are fine, but aren't required (and may be less efficient depending on your string lengths).  You could also do simply:

```
s1 = "bird"
s2 = "irbd"

print all(l in s1 for l in s2)  # True
```

Note that this will stop immediately as soon as a letter in `s2` isn't found in `s1` and return `False`.

Comment: This will run in `O(n * m)` since it will repeatedly iterate through s2. Consider "aaaaa" and "bbbba". Using sets it will run in `O(n)` or `O(m)` whichever is greater.

Comment: Worst-case, yes.  It will also short-circuit, however -- a feature of generators that you shouldn't overlook.

Comment: Performance will depend on the composition of the strings.  Sets guarantee that you'll iterate over each entire list. This approach *could* exit after a single iteration over `s2`.  If the lists contain many duplicate values, then performance favors using sets.  If it's unlikely that `s1` is a subset of `s2` then performance will favor this approach.  Memory may play a factor as well, etc.