# Evaluating whether a string is a subanagram of another

Tags: python, string, function

I would like to create a function with 2 arguments (x,y) ,x and y is a string, and returns true if x is a sub anagram of y. example: "red" is a sub anagram of "reda" but "reda" is not a sub anagram of "red".

So far what I have got:
I have turned x,y into list and then sorted them. That way I can compare the alphabets from each string.

```
def sub_anagram(str1, str2):
    s1 = list(str1)
    s2 = list(str2)
    s1.sort()
    s2.sort()
    for letters in s2:
        if letters in s1: 
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What I am confused with:
I want to compare the string y to x and if y contains all the characters from x then it returns true otherwise false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return True if all characters in a string are in another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997056/return-true-if-all-characters-in-a-string-are-in-another-string)

Comment: @ZN13 Not so - think about comparing "reed" and "red", without returning `True` when evaluating whether "reed" is a subanagram of "red"

Comment: Is a word a subanagram of itself?  Or does a subanagram have to be strictly smaller than the original?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter
def subanagram(str1, str2):
    str1_counter, str2_counter = Counter(str1), Counter(str2)
    return all(str1_counter[char] <= str2_counter[char]
                 for char in str1_counter)
```

In the code above, `str1_counter` is basically a dictionary with the characters appearing in `str1` and their frequency as the key, value.  Similarly for `str2_counter`.

Then the code checks that for all characters in `str1`, that character appears at least as many times in `str2` as it does in `str1`.

**Edit:** If a subanagram is defined to be strictly smaller than the original, e.g. you want `subanagram("red", "red")` to be `False`, then first compare the two counters for equality.

```
from collections import Counter
def subanagram(str1, str2):
    str1_counter, str2_counter = Counter(str1), Counter(str2)
    if str1_counter == str2_counter:
        return False
    return all(str1_counter[char] <= str2_counter[char]
                 for char in str1_counter)
```

If I were *not* using `Counter` for some reason, it would be something along the lines of:

```
def subanagram(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) == len(str2):
        return False  #Ensures strict subanagram

    s2 = list(str2)
    try:
        for char in str1:
            s2.remove(char)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

But as you can see, it is longer, less declarative and less efficient than using `Counter`.

Comment: thank you! it worked but how would i write it without using counter?

Comment: Hmm, probably something like combining `try-except ValueError` with `for char in s1: s2.remove(char)` - not the most efficient, and I would always use `Counter` for something like this personally because it feels more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just check for each character in x being present in y, as this does not account for a character being repeated in x.  In other words, 'reeeeed' is not a sub-anagram of 'reda'.

This is one way to do it:

1. make a copy of y
2. for each character in x, if that character is present in the y-copy, remove it from the y-copy.  if it isn't present, return false.
3. if you reach the end of the loop and the y-copy is empty, return false.  (x is an anagram, but not a sub-anagram.)
4. otherwise return true.

Comment: How would i make a copy of y? Ive got this so far but i just cant figure out how to check and remove
def ana(str1, str2):
    s1 = list(str1)
    s2 = list(str2)
    s1.sort()
    s2.sort()
    for letters in s2:
        if letters in s1: 
            print (letters, )
        else:
            return False

Comment: Hey, i have done that but I would like to know how to do the 2nd and 3rd part of what you said.

Comment: You have to show some effort.  We're not going to write your whole program for you.

Comment: I have been trying to write this for long time. I have edited the post to show what I have got so far but it just doesnt click in my head how to carry on from there.